# How to distinguish between a const reference and the const of the referenced object?

Tags: c++, c++20

I want to implement the following code:

```
void Foo (const myobj& obj, const std::vector<std::string>& paths)
{
  const auto& temp = obj;
  for(const auto str : paths)
    temp = temp.find(str); // find is a const method

  // read something from temp here (const access only)
}
```

Unfortunately that doesn't work, because temp cannot be reassigned (cause it is const). If I remove the const from temp however, I cannot assign obj anymore, because it is const.

How to distinguish in C++ between the const that refers to the object and the const that refers to the reference? I know it's possible with pointers (syntax: const in front or behind `*`). However, I couldn't find something like that for references.

If there is no such way for references, how to properly implement the function I've shown above?

Comment: "*How to distinguish in C++ between the const that refers to the object and the const that refers to the reference?*" The latter does not exist. Or rather, references are *always* `const` because you can never rebind them. So `const` when used with a reference always refers to the type being referenced.

Comment: OK, that would suggest that I can't use references for the above code at all. Is there another way to implement Foo? (without changing myobj or its signature - both not under my control).

Comment: "*how to properly implement the function I've shown above?*" If you said you wanted to take a parameter you can't modify, but you want to modify it anyway, your interface is lying. Stop lying about it and either copy the string or take a non-`const` reference.

Comment: To clarify - is the goal of your function to accept a `const myobj&` and change that object?  There are sometimes ways to do that, but "properly" may not be a fitting adverb.

Comment: @DrewDormann: Why do you want to overwrite `obj`?

Comment: @NicolBolas I can't say that I do.  Did you mis-"@" me?

Comment: I don't want to change the obj in any way. I just want to drill down the object using it's find() method and then read something. All methods I'm calling on `obj` are const (find and the read at the end which i've not shown)

Comment: Change `const auto& temp = obj;` to `auto temp = obj;`, and Bob's your Uncle.

Comment: @Eljay: that's creating unnecessary copies then, I don't want that. Raymond Chen has given me a solution down in the comments of the first answer.

Comment: Yes it does. Actually your comment below already did, thanks. If you want to post it as an answer I can accept it. I suspect you're _the_ Raymond Chen, in that case: nice blog, I'm a daily reader :)

Comment: Given that this code wants a variable to change what object it is referring to, I feel that a pointer is the most natural type to communicate and achieve this.  `const auto* temp = &obj;`